# How to create JSF page which displays text log file with lazy loading

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I want to display JSF page which displays the content of a Glassfish's log file. So far I have done only this:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
    import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
    import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
    import javax.inject.Named;

    @Named("GlassfishLogFileController")
    @ViewScoped
    public class GlassfishLogFile implements Serializable
    {

        String id;
        String fileData;

        // Constructor
        public GlassfishLogFile()
        {
            // Get the ID value 
            try
            {
                this.id = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.id = null;
            }
        }
        // Path for Glassfish directory with log files
        String path = "/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/" + id;

        @PostConstruct
        public void redFile()
        {
            File file = new File(path);

            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file))
            {

                int content;
                while ((content = fis.read()) != -1)
                {
                    // convert to char and display it
                    fileData = fileData + (char)content;
                }

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public String getdata()
        {
            return fileData;
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<div id="settingsdiv" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">

    <div id="settingsHashMap" style="width:1050px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">

        <h:form id="form" >
            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />

            <h:inputTextarea rows="30" cols="50" value="#{GlassfishLogFileController.data}" />                            

        </h:form>                    
    </div> 

</div>
```

I'm interested is there any possible way to implement lazy loading into the text area which I will use to display the content of the text file. I want to do this because I want to save memory. Log files sometimes can be very memory consuming.

And also I found many examples how to display .pdf documents into JSF page but none of them how to display text document into text area.

Best wishes

P.S I updated the code. Now I get empty input field. No data from the log file is displayed.

Comment: Off topic but you have CDI Named bean with faces ViewScoped, which obviously wont work.  Named beans are managed by CDI, whereas ManagedBeans are managed by jsf...

Comment: I suppose that I can do this with getter/setter?

Comment: I would just display lines 20 lines at a time and have an event loading the remaining lines on some event (click, focus etc...)

Comment: Can you give some basic example?

Comment: Look into implementing an ajax push mechanism and a file watcher service to notify your jsf of any log file changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I have just tested it:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@Named("GlassfishLogFileController")
@ViewScoped
public class GlassfishLogFile implements Serializable {

String data;

String id;

private int offset = 0;
private int pageSize = 30;
// Path for Glassfish directory with log files
String path = "/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/" + this.id;

// Constructor
public GlassfishLogFile() {
// Get the ID value
try {
    this.id = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
    // We load the first page initially!
    this.actionNextPage();
} catch (Exception e) {
    this.id = null;
}
}

public String actionClearOffset() {
this.offset = 0;
this.actionNextPage();
return "SUCCESS";
}

public String actionNextPage() {
StringBuilder page = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < this.pageSize; i++) {
    String line = this.readLine(this.offset);
    if (line == null) {
    break;
    }
    System.out.println(this.offset);
    this.offset += line.length() + 2;
    page.append(line).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
this.data = page.toString();
return "SUCCESS";
}

public String getData() {
return this.data;
}

public int getPageSize() {
return this.pageSize;
}

public String readLine(long offset) {
String strLine = null;
DataInputStream in = null;
try {
    // Open the file that is the first
    // command line parameter
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(new File(this.path));
    // Get the object of DataInputStream
    in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    br.skip(offset);

    strLine = br.readLine();
    // Close the input stream
} catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
} finally {
    try {
    in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
return strLine;
}

public void setData(String data) {

}
}
```

View:

```
<div id="settingsdiv" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">

    <div id="settingsHashMap" style="width:1050px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">

        <h:form id="form" >
            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />

            <h:commandButton value="Show next #{GlassfishLogFileController.pageSize} lines" 
                                 action="#{GlassfishLogFileController.actionNextPage}" />
            <h:commandButton value="Clear offset" 
                                 action="#{GlassfishLogFileController.actionClearOffset}" />
            <h:inputTextarea rows="30" cols="1000" value="#{GlassfishLogFileController.data}" />   
        </h:form>                    
    </div> 

</div>
```